# `String` is on the dynamic heap, so why when I push to it, I need to mark it `mut`?

Tags: rust

`String` is on the dynamic heap in Rust, so why when I push to it, I need to mark it `mut`?

Code:

```rust
fn ct(input: &str) -> String {
    let result = input.to_string();
    result.push_str(" world");
    result
}
```

If "result" is on the dynamic heap, why do I still need to set it for `mut` type?

Error:

```
error[E0596]: cannot borrow `result` as mutable, as it is not declared as mutable
 --> src/lib.rs:3:5
  |
3 |     result.push_str(" world");
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot borrow as mutable
  |
help: consider changing this to be mutable
  |
2 |     let mut result = input.to_string();
  |         +++
```

How should I understand that?

Comment: Everywhere you want to change a variable in Rust, you need to mark it `mut` (unless it contains interior mutability). It is not related to stack/heap.

Answer (score 3):

Mutability is controlled first by the owner of the value. When you have an immutable value, you can add mutability by moving the value to a new owner, but you can't add mutability by giving out a reference, only preserve existing mutability. Since `push_str` needs `&mut self`, the value needs to be already owned mutably to call it.

In rust, heap values are owned (usually). You're probably thinking of other languages where heap values are always references, and only primitives, such as integers and pointers, can be owned in the rust sense.